# "RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different appartment" tkinter and threading

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, tcl

I want to implement GUI using threading and tkinter (**python 3.6**). 
When I run GUIExecution.py, the following error occurs. 
"**RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different appartment**" on self.root.mainloop() in base_gui_class.py 
I am implementing it on a class basis, and the three code files are as follows. 
The executable file is GUIExecution.py.
I spent a lot of time trying to fix the error, but I have not been able to fix it yet. 
Please give a lot of advice. 
**Additionally, if I run the following code in a python2 environment, it works fine without error.**

GUIExecution.py

```
from base_gui_class import *

from base_class import *

speed = 1000
height = 500
width = 700

base_model = base_class()
gui = base_gui_class(base_model, speed, height, width)
base_model.visualize()
```

base_class.py

```
class base_class():
    genes = []
    dicLocations = {}
    gui = ''
    best = ''
    time = 0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def visualize(self):
        if self.gui != '':
            self.gui.start()

    def registerGUI(self, gui):
        self.gui = gui
```

base_gui_class.py

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import math
import threading
import time
class base_gui_class(threading.Thread):
    root = ''
    canvas = ''
    speed = 0
    base_model = ''
def __init__(self, base_model, speed, h, w):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.base_model = base_model
    base_model.registerGUI(self)

    self.root = tk.Tk()

    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, height=h, width=w)
    self.canvas.pack()

    self.root.title("Test")
    self.speed = 1 / speed
def run(self):
    self.root.mainloop()
def update(self):
    time.sleep(self.speed)
    width = int(self.canvas.cget("width"))
    height = int(self.canvas.cget("height"))
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, width, height, fill='white')
def stop(self):
    self.root.quit()
```

Answer (score 26):

To a very good first and second approximation, the core of Tk is single threaded. It can be used from multiple threads, but only by initialising it separately in *each* of those threads. Internally, it uses thread-specific variables extensively to avoid the need for major locking (that is, it has nothing like a big Global Interpreter Lock) but that means you *must not* cheat. Whatever thread initialises a Tk context must be the only thread that interacts with that Tk context. **This includes loading the Tkinter module** so you are effectively restricted to using Tkinter from your main thread only; working around this is serious expert's-only stuff.

I recommend that you make your worker threads make changes to your GUI by posting events to it using a queue (or otherwise interlock with critical sections and condition variables, though I find queues easier in practice).

Answer (score 2):

pip install tkthread

#call the function which shows error like this:

tkthread.call_nosync(yourfunction)

this tkthread library handles all the threading internally by itself.

I recommend you reading the documentation of this library:https://pypi.org/project/tkthread/ .

Comment: Answer will look better when using markdown rules - stackoverflow.com/editing-help