# Thread won't stop until window is destroyed, window won't destroy unless thread is stopped

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, infinite-loop

So I have a window which is controlled by a thread that runs in the background and changes the GUI when necessary, at some point this thread will be instructed to change window (involving destroying the window it is in and starting up another window), but this never happens because the thread won't stop executing until the window is changed.

Below is a simplified example:

```
class Window1:
    def __init__(...):
        self.Master = tk.Tk()
        # some code
        self.BackgroundUpdates = threading.Thread(target=self.ActiveWindow)
        self.BackgroundUpdates.start()

    def ActiveWindow(self):
        # gets some instruction
        if instruction == 'next window':
            nextWindow(self)

    def StartWindow(self):
        self.Master.mainloop()

    def KillWindow(self):
        self.Master.destroy()


class Window2:
    def __init__(...):
        self.Master = tk.Tk()
        # some code...

    def StartWindow(self):
        self.Master.mainloop()


def nextWindow(objectWindow):
    objectWindow.KillWindow()
    # when this function is called it never gets past the line above
    nextWindow = Window2()
    nextWindow.StartWindow()

application = Window1()
application.StartWindow()
```

Is there a way that I could rearrange the way I handle the thread so that I don't run into this problem?

a runnable example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Master = tk.Tk()
        self.Frame = tk.Frame(self.Master, width=100, height=100)
        self.Frame.pack()
        self.Updates = threading.Thread(target=self.BackgroundUpdates)
        self.Updates.start()

    def BackgroundUpdates(self):
        # imagine instructions to be a really long list with each element being a 
        # different instruction
        instructions = ['instruction1', 'instruction2', 'next window']
        while True:
            if instructions[0] == 'next window':
                ChangeWindow(self)
            else:
                instructions.remove(instructions[0])

    def StartWindow(self):
        self.Master.mainloop()

    def KillWindow(self):
        self.Master.destroy()

class SecondaryWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Master = tk.Tk()
        self.Frame = tk.Frame(self.Master, width=100, height=100)
        self.Frame.pack()

    def StartWindow(self):
        self.Master.mainloop()

    def KillWindow(self):
        self.Master.destroy()

def ChangeWindow(oldObject):
    oldObject.KillWindow()
    # the line above will halt the program, since it has to wait on the thread to 
    # finish before the window can be destroyed, but this function is being called 
    # from within the thread and so the thread will never stop executing
    del oldObject
    newObject = SecondaryWindow()
    newObject.StartWindow()

window = MainWindow()
window.StartWindow()
```

Comment: your code doesn't even run

Comment: @coderoftheday i've simplified it A LOT from how it is in my program, idk if this actual here code runs, its just to show the general problem

Comment: well your code isn't clear enough to understand your question, try provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that tkinter is singularly threaded, it can be explained more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45803955/11702354

The problem was that I was trying to destroy my window from a different thread to the one it was created in. To solve this problem I had to use the 'after' method from the Tkinter module as well as using a event, this meant that I could control the background stuff (i.e. wait on a specific command from my connected server) and when I needed to change the window I would set the event.

Part of my adapted code can be seen below:

```
    def CheckEvent(self):
        if LOBBY_EVENT.is_set():
            ChangeWindow(self, 'game')
        self.Master.after(5000, self.CheckEvent)

    def StartWindow(self):
        self.Master.after(5000, self.CheckEvent)
        self.Master.after(2000, self.HandleInstruction)
        self.Master.mainloop()
```

So whenever I was calling the StartWindow method for my window, it would check whether the event has been set every 5 seconds, and then every 2 seconds it would go to a separate function 'HandleInstruction' which allowed me to create a response in my GUI (I also used queues to pass information to this function)

I hope this clears up confusion if anyone is to stumble across it!