# Tkinter mainloop in background

Tags: python, tkinter, model-view-controller

I want to run the tkinter mainloop in the background because I´m following the MVC Pattern, so the Controller gets a Interfaceobject to handle all cares. So I tried to thread it. RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different apartment occures. Saw no further answers on this topic.
Does anyone have a clue what to do?

Thanks, Max

Answer (score 0):

I don´t have the solution you want for this problem. Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799121/runtimeerror-calling-tcl-from-different-appartment-tkinter-and-threading) is can show you what happens.

Anyway you can try by defining all tkinter objects inside the function like this:

```
from tkinter import Tk
import threading

def mainloop():
    root = Tk()
    #Your tkinter objects goes here
    root.mainloop()

t = threading.Thread(target=mainloop)
t.start()
```

or you can run the mainloop without threading and thread the Controller:

```
from tkinter import Tk
import threading

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()

def controler():
    while True:
        pass

t = threading.Thread(target=controler)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Tomás Gomez Pizarro for one solution. I myself came up with a solution. My Controller etc are set up with a reference(Object) to my Gui. the Gui itself, so the mainloop function is not called until everything is ready. So in Runtime every GuiEvent is passed to the Controller via a thread so that the main loop is not interferred with.

Regards, Max