# Why can't tkinter run in other threads on OSX?

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, tkinter

When calling `mainloop()` for a `Tk` on MacOS in a thread beside the same one, it fails with a `RuntimeError: calling Tcl from different apartment`.

However, if I do this on Linux, it works fine.

Why does this happen on MacOS only?
Is there any way around this?

*Test code:*

```py
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def start_tk_with_mainloop():
    x = tk.Tk()
    x.mainloop()

thread = threading.Thread(target=start_tk_with_mainloop)
thread.start()
```

*Note:*
This is not a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799121/runtimeerror-calling-tcl-from-different-appartment-tkinter-and-threading) because this question is specifically about why it only happens on MacOS.

`tkinter.TkVersion`: `8.6`

`python`: `3.6`

Comment: It might be worth printing your `tk.TkVersion`

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45799121/7432). The only answer to that question was written by someone who helped write part of tcl/tk upon which tkinter is built.

Comment: It partly depends on how `tkinter` was built.  There's a long discussion in the source code:  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f26fec4f74ae7da972595703bc39d3d30b8cfdf9/Modules/_tkinter.c#L178